# How can I use SSH tunneling to connect to a remote MySQL server?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, tunneling

I'm using SSH tunneling for the first time, so I'm trying to understand how to configure it.

I've got a remote Linux server that hosts a MySQL database that I'm trying to connect to. In order to access the MySQL database directly through a software that only recognizes local databases, I suppose SSH tunneling would be the right way to set up the access, correct?

Now, I'm trying to set up the tunneling on my 'home' computer which is running the software that's trying to access the MySQL database. My first question is whether this is reverse tunneling or normal tunneling? Secondly, is it local tunneling or remote tunneling?

Finally, from what I understand, my code is supposed to look something like

```
ssh -L 8080:mylinuxserver.mycompany.com:22 myuser@mylinuxserver.mycompany.com
```

Is this correct? Is my source port '22' since I'm using SSH and is my destination port 8080 (or is there something more appropriate)?

When I try to use the above code, I am able to login using my passphrase (since my key is already in the MyLinuxServer) but when I ping localhost:8080, it cannot find the host.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I've got a remote Linux server that hosts a MySQL database that I'm trying to connect to

The command should be:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:3306 myuser@mylinuxserver.mycompany.com
```

Where:

1. **8080**: is hte local port on your workstation
2. **localhost**: is corresponding to `mylinuxserver.mycompany.com`
3. **3306**: the MySQL port on above `localhost`.

then connect (from your workstation) to MySQL as:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --port=8080
```

Besides, `ping localhost:8080` is wrong. `Ping` cannot work that way.

Comment: In my case, terminal accepted port as mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p -P 8080;

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
ssh -f ssh_user@mylinuxserver.mycompany.com -L 3307:mysql1.example.com:3306 -N
```

Next, to access the mysql your trying to connect to:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307
```

Comment: It executed correctly but I still can't successfully ping it because it can't find the host. Same issue as I had with the code I've put in my question.

Comment: When I try to run the mysql command, it shows that the command was not found.